# Adding images,text and videos to a flutter application

Tags: image, video, flutter

I would like little help. I'm building an e-commerce app with video support an 
i would like two things, if there's a tutorial / manual page link out there to show these two I would much appreciate the help.

1) I would like to be able to **add images** and **text** like on the "Shop for" section in the image below (that is the part surrounded by the red rectangle). My goal is to add categories with images.

[image]

2) Looking at the card on "Trending" (surrounded by the green rectangle), on that is there way to place a video inside a card like the laptop in the card to be playing?

[image]

Comment: [Play and pause a video - Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video)

Comment: I don't use Flutter (you tagged `video`) but you need to find out how to make a [**Container** object](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout). Then for (1) it can now contain your **Grid List** or **Grid View** and for (2) it can contain your text, icon images, and video object.